# Enabling Session State in Share Point 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I m trying to enable Session State for my Share Point web. I followed the steps

**1)Added
< httpModules > < add name = "Session " type = "System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule " /> 
 
THEN, added the same session state module to the IIS7 managed pipeline by following the steps


1.Open IIS 7 manager, and find your web application.

2.Double click "Modules" in the IIS section.

3.Click "Add Managed Module..." on the right hand pane.

4.In the Add Managed Module dialog, enter "SessionState" or something like that for the name, and choose the following item from the dropdown: System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a**

But I am still getting error...

Answer (score 0):

Try these options as well.

- Add  to the
  configuration/system.webServer/modules
  element.
- Set the enableSessionState attribute
  of the configuration/system.web/pages
  element to true.
- Add  to
  the configuration/system.web element.

  More details available [here](http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=123)